# BottomNavigationBar en Flutter

Tags: flutter

El código en el que estoy trabajando tiene un menú inferior (`BottomNavigationBar`) con 4 íconos los cuales al dar touch me dirigen a una página en específico, pero yo al darle clic a un botón que dirige a otra página y ya en esa página el ícono sigue como activo y yo al querer regresar a la página anterior dando touch al mismo ícono ya no me lo permite. Si doy touch a otro icono del menú y regreso sí lo hace, pero no quiero que el usuario haga eso.

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora en cuestión del `BottomNavigationBar`.

Código del menú inferior:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../pages/icon_medi_icons.dart';

class BarNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function currentIndex;
  const BarNavigator({Key? key, required this.currentIndex}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BarNavigatorState createState() => _BarNavigatorState();
}

class _BarNavigatorState extends State<BarNavigator> {
  int index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int i) {
          setState(() {
            index = i;
            widget.currentIndex(i);
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF38B6FF),
        iconSize: 50,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(IconMedi.home),
            label: 'Inicio',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(IconMedi.pacientes_menu_inferior),
            label: 'Pacientes',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(IconMedi.evaluaciones), label: 'Evaluaciones'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(IconMedi.mi_cuenta_inactivo_menu), label: 'Mi Cuenta'),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Código de rutas del menú inferior:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:medi_planner/pages/crear_paciente_page.dart';
import 'package:medi_planner/pages/cuenta_page.dart';
import 'package:medi_planner/pages/evaluaciones_page.dart';
import 'package:medi_planner/pages/inicio_page.dart';

class Routes extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const Routes({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> myList = [
      const InicioPage(),
      ListadoPacientes(),
      const EvaluacionesPage(),
      const Pruebas(),
    ];
    return myList[index];
  }
```

Código del main:

```
class menu extends StatefulWidget {
  const menu({super.key});

  @override
  State<menu> createState() => _menuState();
}

class _menuState extends State<menu> {
  int index = 0;
  BarNavigator? myBNB;
  @override
  void initState() {
    myBNB = BarNavigator(currentIndex: (i) {
      setState(() {
        index = i;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: myBNB,
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: index,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el código proporcionado, la variable `index` en la clase `_menuState` se utiliza para mantener el índice del elemento seleccionado actualmente en el `BottomNavigationBar`. Sin embargo, la misma variable también se utiliza para determinar qué página mostrar en el `IndexedStack`.

Para solucionar el problema necesitas mantener un estado separado para cada página y actualizar el estado del `BottomNavigationBar` y el `IndexedStack` por separado. Una forma de hacerlo es utilizando el `widget PageView` en lugar de `IndexedStack`. El `PageView` maneja automáticamente el estado de cada página y permite que el usuario se desplace entre ellas deslizando el dedo.

Te dejo por aquí una idea de como hacerlo:

```
class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuPageState createState() => _MenuPageState();
}

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    const InicioPage(),
    const ListadoPacientes(),
    const EvaluacionesPage(),
    const Pruebas(),
  ];

  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onPageChanged,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: const Color(0xFF38B6FF),
        iconSize: 50,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(IconMedi.home),
            label: 'Inicio',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(IconMedi.pacientes_menu_inferior),
            label: 'Pacientes',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(IconMedi.evaluaciones),
            label: 'Evaluaciones',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(IconMedi.mi_cuenta_inactivo_menu),
            label: 'Mi Cuenta',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: _pages,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Aquí, `_selectedIndex` se utiliza para mantener el índice de la página seleccionada en el `BottomNavigationBar`. El método `_onPageChanged` se llama cuando el usuario toca un elemento en el `BottomNavigationBar` o desliza el dedo para cambiar de página en el `PageView`. Este método actualiza el estado de `_selectedIndex`, lo que a su vez actualiza el `BottomNavigationBar` y el `PageView`.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.